# Facebook API how to use a token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I'm sorry if this question is stupid, but how do I actually use the token after I get it (and validate it)? I'm running a Desktop application for which I'm trying to get Facebook login working. I've managed to grab the token, but I do not know how to use it in a request (for example, to get a user's e-mail). I mean, what form would a request that also contains the token look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the correct form:

`https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=name,email&access_token=xxx`